# Microsoft Graph API - Calendar Event ChangeTracking Issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to create an event whose start/end date is of older time from current. Below is the request,

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/

Body:
{
  "subject": "Test Old Event",
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2019-12-20T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2019-12-20T14:00:00",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
  }
}
```

Got a response for the same as below,

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('f7edf005-0451-49de-bae1-a1794b528434')/events/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"3zxKTWNb1k2PdgXN3kcaBAAAndJKqg==\"",
    "id": "AAMkAGEwOTJkZjE2LWRhYTYtNDdmMS04NTcxLTIxOThlZDBhMjhlOABGAAAAAACQXz1o19PeQKBkV5TRqGKvBwDfPEpNY1vWTY92Bc3eRxoEAAAAAAENAADfPEpNY1vWTY92Bc3eRxoEAACd2xkjAAA=",
    "createdDateTime": "2019-12-22T17:14:28.5309555Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-12-22T17:14:28.7428321Z",
    "changeKey": "3zxKTWNb1k2PdgXN3kcaBAAAndJKqg==",
    "categories": [],
    "originalStartTimeZone": "UTC",
    "originalEndTimeZone": "UTC",
    "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000902B9E44EBB8D50100000000000000001000000012260EC65CA7EF479B8B92A81A06129F",
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
    "isReminderOn": true,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "Test Old Event",
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isCancelled": false,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "showAs": "busy",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=AAMkAGEwOTJkZjE2LWRhYTYtNDdmMS04NTcxLTIxOThlZDBhMjhlOABGAAAAAACQXz1o19PeQKBkV5TRqGKvBwDfPEpNY1vWTY92Bc3eRxoEAAAAAAENAADfPEpNY1vWTY92Bc3eRxoEAACd2xkjAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
    "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
    "recurrence": null,
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "organizer",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "body": {
        "contentType": "text",
        "content": ""
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2019-12-20T12:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2019-12-20T14:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "",
        "locationType": "default",
        "uniqueIdType": "unknown",
        "address": {},
        "coordinates": {}
    },
    "locations": [],
    "attendees": [],
    "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "NAME",
            "address": "EMAIL"
        }
    }
}
```

I created graph subscription to get notified of any changes on my calendar events as below.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-type: application/json

{
   "changeType": "updated,created,deleted",
   "notificationUrl": "<MY_WEBHOOK>",
   "resource": "me/events",
   "clientState": "<state>"
}
```

For the above create event I did, I got notified of some change through the webhook.

I queried the changes to calendar events using delta query.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview/delta?$deltatoken=<DELTA_TOKEN_URL>
```

Below is the response I have got from graph, on the event I created above through delta query API.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(event)",
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview/delta?$deltatoken=<DELTA_TOKEN_URL>",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.event",
            "id": "AAMkAGEwOTJkZjE2LWRhYTYtNDdmMS04NTcxLTIxOThlZDBhMjhlOABGAAAAAACQXz1o19PeQKBkV5TRqGKvBwDfPEpNY1vWTY92Bc3eRxoEAAAAAAENAADfPEpNY1vWTY92Bc3eRxoEAACd2xkjAAA=",
            "@removed": {
                "reason": "deleted"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see in the above response, the event I just created is being returned as `@removed` i.e deleted, which is incorrect.

This is only happening to events I am creating for an older time.

Hope you fix this issue as soon as you can.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. There isn't enough information to go on here.

Comment: Hey @MarcLaFleur , edited it. Please check now. Thanks.

Comment: Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, I have tested the same again (via API's) and seems its working fine with delta query now. But if I make changes directly from calendar, then the issue is still reproducible. Please confirm on this, if you are aware of this new observation.
Thanks.